# Wordpress HTML Formatting

Tags: html, wordpress

I installed the Blank Slate plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/blank-slate/) for Wordpress and I was able to drop some HTML into a Wordpress page and get that working.

I'd like to still use my website's header and footer on the page but I don't know how to do that if I'm using the Blank Slate plugin.

Also, if I use a sidebar on the page then the HTML gets messed up and doesn't look right.

[image]

Comment: Looking at the plugin page, it says it removes the header and footer. Perhaps this is the wrong plugin for you to use. I better place to ask a question would be the support forum on the plugin's page.

Comment: Somewhere in the filesystem, you should be able to find the template or index page where the information is called from. Possibly in the plugin files, you can try to add include("header.php") and include("footer.php") which should call your sites header and footer.